# VB.NET - TreeView Node click - how to get node's key?

Tags: vb.net, treeview

I'm building treeview programmatically, and getting information about each clicked node from a remote server. Each node has a unique key.

```
SForm.PosTreeView.Nodes.Add("Key1", "Vegetables")
SForm.PosTreeView.Nodes.Add("Key2", "Fruits")
SForm.PosTreeView.Nodes("Key2").Nodes.Add("Key3", "Pineapple")
```

Question: How to get the key of clicked node?
E.g. get Key3 after clicking on "Pineapple".

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Get Key by node's Name - is not an option, multiple nodes can have the same name.

Comment: You shouldn't need to ask that question here because the answer is contained in the documentation for the `Add` method that you're calling. If you haven't read the relevant documentation then you haven't tried so asking a question here is premature.

Comment: You stated in your question that each node has a unique key and now you contradict yourself and say that two nodes can have the same `Name`. You're not actually making sense.

Comment: jmcilhinney, I think you misunderstad something. Node's key != node's Name. Example: `SForm.PosTreeView.Nodes("Key1").Nodes.Add("Key4", "Pineapple")`

Comment: No, I think that it's you who doesn't understand something. I'm talking about the `Name` property, not the `Text` property whose value is displayed on the node. You obviously still haven't read the documentation which outright states that the key corresponds to the `Name`. You're wasting my time and your own.

Comment: My bad, sorry :)

Comment: All's well that ends well.

Answer (score 3):

**Node.Name** - that's what i needed.

```
Private Sub PosTreeView_AfterSelect(sender As Object, e As TreeViewEventArgs) 
Handles PosTreeView.AfterSelect
    Console.WriteLine(e.Node.Name)
End Sub
```